# Adding Drop down input to a search form

Tags: html, search, drop-down-menu

I have a search form which collects an address and passes it to my php.

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" id="search-form" action=/php/search.php method="post">
  <input type="search" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address?" value="" />
  <button id="search" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

The html/css code is on this jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/maverick_r77/A7j3q/

I would like to add an drop-down option to the form so that users can specify the "address type".

```
<select id="addrType">
  <option value="1">Residential</option>
  <option value="2">Commercial</option>
</select>
```

Here's the Jfiddle with the drop-down option - jsfiddle.net/maverick_r77/85xnU/.

I would like to align the drop-down right between the search window and the search button but the alignment is getting all messed up.

Essentially, I'm trying to create something like the searchbox on http://www.goby.com/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, your question concerns more HTML than PHP ('look' and not 'inner works'). Consider using CSS property [display:table-cell](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) or [some grid system](http://960.gs/).

Comment: Thanks Jderda for your input. I will investigate both suggestions. And yes, the question is more regarding html and css styling. Thanks for editing the tags in the original question.